# Get Queued Task count and running Task count in Python ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am using Python 'ThreadPoolExecutor` to run my tasks in Parallel.

```py
import concurrent.futures, time

poolx = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
poolx.submit(time.sleep, 3)
poolx.submit(time.sleep, 3)
poolx.submit(time.sleep, 3)
poolx.submit(time.sleep, 0)   # very fast
```

I wanted to know

1. how many task are in queued status or Pending status?
2. how many task are in running status?

Answer (score 2):

When you submit to the ThreadPoolExecutor, a Future object is returned. You can determine a thread's state by examination of such an object. Here's an example:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

def runningthreadcount(futures):
    r = 0
    for future in futures:
        if future.running():
            r += 1
    print(f'{r} threads running')
    return r

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = []
    for i in range(10):
        futures.append(executor.submit(time.sleep, i+1))
    while runningthreadcount(futures) > 0:
        time.sleep(1)
```